# Media Player not removed using MediaSource and webRTC streaming

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, media-source

I am trying to stream multiple media files (sequentially) from one webRTC device to another using the mediasource API on the receive side. The files are received and played on the same video source element on the page but each time i stream a new file (or the sameone over again), a player shows up on the Google chrome://media-internals/ but the other players from the prior transmissions are also still shown.

My concern is that resources have been allocated but are not released (or more likely i am not doing something correctly) when a new mediasource is allocated for the new stream (from the webRTC).

Any thoughts on how to explicitly release or remote a mediasource which was allocated and played?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a different peer connection for each stream and in addition you should call stop() on the media stream. As part of the clean up between playback instances, you may also want to clear the link to the stream in the element like so:

```
if (moz) {
  document.getElementById('yourvideoelementid').mozSrcObject = undefined;
} else {
  document.getElementById('yourvideoelementid').src = "";
}
```

The *moz* indicates the browser is Mozilla/Firefox.

Comment: Hi Mondain, thanks for your input, got tied up on real work for a while, anyway, was a little unclear about calling stop() - on the mediasource? the   receive buffer? or the peer stream - in the case of the peer stream, it seems to me that this should be largely independent of the mediasource api handling - thoughts?

Comment: MediaStream.stop() is mainly what I wanted to focus on.

Comment: via navigator.mozGetUserMedia() or navigator.webkitGetUserMedia()

Comment: So, in my case, i am not using GetUserMedia for the mediaSource API processing - a webM file is streamed over the RTC data connection and is received on the remote side and buffered on a MediaSource buffer (e.g., recvMediaSource = new MediaSource();
        recvMediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function (e) {
            consoleLog('media source state: ', this.readyState);
            // get a buffer to receive into, specifiying the data type
            receiverBuffer = recvMediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
            }

Comment: I'm not sure how or if the media stream and media source are interoperable

Comment: Sorry, if i was not clear, i am not trying to take a mediastream to mediasource, i am only using the rtc dataconnection

Comment: From what I read, I think what you have to do in your case is to get the readyState to "closed"; https://w3c.github.io/media-source/#mediasource-detach

Comment: thanks, will play around with it and let you know if something works